# Struggling with ajax file upload

Tags: jquery, ajax

If I just use the serialised form as the data I can get it to work but since I have tried to include uploading a file too it fails, it does nothing?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#advice_submit').click(function(e){
     var formData = new FormData($('form#ask_advice_form')[0]); 
              $.ajax({
              url: 'ajax/ask_advice_ajax.php',
              type:'POST',
              data: formData,
              dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    $('#success').html(response.question_id+' '+response.user); 
                }, // End of success function of ajax form
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
             }
        }); // End of ajax call 
     });//close whole function
  });//close whole function
```

The form

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="ask_advice_form">
         <input type="text" id="desc" name="desc"  maxlength="50">
         <textarea name="advice_question" id="advice_question"></textarea>
         <input type="file" name="file" id="image" style="border:none">
    <input type="button" name="advice_submit" id="advice_submit" value=""
          class="request_opinion white_submit" >
     </form>
```

Comment: Are you confident that your code is 100% correct?

Comment: which code?  I know the ask_advice_ajax.php is correct because ot works with the serialised form, I'm not convinced about the jquery

Comment: How does it fail?  Is there an error from the server?  An error on the JavaScript console?  When you compare it with the working version, what's different about the request it generates?

Comment: 3 things: 1) Make sure your `<form>` tag is closed 2) Did you test without ajax? 3) What browser are you using?

Comment: Its serialising the FormData Object including the append function which it executes without any parameters, this fails and you get the problem.

Comment: I've set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PWUf/) example

Comment: @SaintGerbil - I've looked at the fiddle but all I can see is different is the close of the form tag (which does exist in my original code, I just forgot to add it to the original question

Comment: And you can see the source of the problem.

Comment: @David - I get no error messages, it does absolutely nothing, either on screen or in the console

Comment: @SaintGerbil - are you saying the lack of the closing form tag is the issue?  It does exist in my code, I had forgotten to add it to the question is all

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work using this...

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#advice_submit").click( function() {
  var formData = new FormData($('#ask_advice_form')[0]);
     $.ajax({
           url: 'ajax/ask_advice_ajax.php',
           data: formData,
           async: false,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           cache: false,
           type: 'POST',
           success: function(response)
           {
               alert('smeg');
           },
         });    return false;    
    });
});
```

Seems I was missing these elements:

```
async: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
cache: false,
```